# How to ignore blank lines in git show stats count?

Tags: git

I am curious if it's possible to get change stats (#inserts/#deletes) by ignoring any newlines in the stats output? If I do an explicit count with `--word-diff` option and count the matching lines for addition (surrounded by `{+...+}`) or deletion (surrounded by `[-...-]`) the counts don't match those output by the `stat`.

It seems a git show of stats includes the blank lines that are inserted/deleted and can substantially inflate their counts.

I tried the flags of `--ignore-blank-lines` and other `ignore-*` flags to no avail.

For example:

```
git show --shortstat --format= abcd1234
 17 files changed, 471 insertions(+), 392 deletions(-)
```

If I do a manual `word-diff` based counting like so the number of inserts is a lot lower:

```
git show abcd1234 --first-parent --unified=0 --word-diff --format= | egrep -v "^@|^diff|^new|^index|^---|^\+\+\+" | egrep "{\+.*\+}$" | wc -l
```

This gives `402`. Repeating for deletes I get `332`. Both lesser than 471 inserts and 392 deletes respectively, output by `shortstat` Any way to "match up" the counts by ignoring the blanklines? If I do not ignore the blank lines, the counts match up just fine.

Comment: You could try `-w, --ignore-all-space` unless you care about whitespace elsewhere

Comment: @JanWilamowski - I have. It doesn't work with the `--stat` or `--numstat` option it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--word-diff` and regular "line diff" are different algorithms.
You have no guarantee that the count of "modified lines" will match.

Other than that :

the stat options (`--stat`, `--numstat`, `--shortstat`) to `git diff` or `git show` do combine with whitespace diff options (such as [`--ignore-blank-lines`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---ignore-blank-lines) or [`-b | --ignore-space-change`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt--b) or [`-w | --ignore-all-space`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt--w)) :

```
# will only count lines with non trivial changes :
git show -b --shortstat
```

---

Regarding the differences between the two algorithms,
as a simple example, take :

```
# fileA                     # fileB
a line a line a line        line a line a line a
a line a line a line        line a line a line a
a line a line a line        line a line a line a
a line a line a line        line a line a line a
a line a line a line        line a line a line a
```

"line wise" : you would have to delete all lines in `fileA` to change it to `fileB`, the stat for such a patch would be `5 insertions, 5 deletions` :

```
$ git diff --no-index fileA fileB
diff --git a/fileA b/fileB
index 38ef89845..f417ca808 100644
--- a/fileA
+++ b/fileB
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
-a line a line a line
-a line a line a line
-a line a line a line
-a line a line a line
-a line a line a line
+line a line a line a
+line a line a line a
+line a line a line a
+line a line a line a
+line a line a line a
```

"word wise" : you would only have to delete the first `a` in `fileA`, and add an extra `a` at the end of `fileB`, your "grep" command would compute `1 insertion, 1 deletion` :

```
$ git diff --word-diff --no-index fileA fileB
diff --git a/fileA b/fileB
index 38ef89845..f417ca808 100644
--- a/fileA
+++ b/fileB
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
[-a-]line a line a line a
line a line a line a
line a line a line a
line a line a line a
line a line a line {+a+}
```

Comment: I see. So does this difference imply impossibility of achieving what I intend? If so, then it’s a valid answer. If not then it is pointing out something that I’m overlooking and may be better to have this as a comment: or more context/direction on how to solve this question may be more helpful IMHO.

Comment: I wanted to underline : given that you compare two completely distinct algorithms, you can't have a solid guarantee that your two lines count will match anyway (it's not limited to whitespace changes). I'll double check the doc to see if `--stat` or `--numstat` can work together with the `--ignore-all-space` option.

Comment: obviously : if you want check by hand (or using grep) that the stats match something you see, just drop `--word-diff` and count the lines starting with `+` or `-` in a regular patch.

Comment: _THIS_ is wonderful. I think I get the idea. The example is a good one to elucidate the differences between line/word diffs. My "meta" purpose was to see how to manually count the "modifications" (delete _and_ insert) with merge commits (if possible). _Technically_ the diff above has 5 _modifications_. Piping the output to `diffstat` does show that so I'll stick with it. Was curious about doing it manually. I see the flaw and am thankful for the update. 

Comment: My only gripe is that I can't get the blank line options to work with `--numstat`. Try adding new lines in between lines in `fileB` and also add a different line of content. `git show --ignore-blank-lines --numstat --format=...` counts the blank lines.  But a `git show` without stat does remove blank lines from output. Stat computation doesn't.

Comment: PS: It worked after adding the `--unified=0` for the above example...but not on the files in my repository (PHP) that has newlines as part of the commit